# gradle installation is not correctly configured

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project and I have imported that project into eclipse, I want to run that project for that I have right click on gradle.build and run as ==> gradle build.

It is saying like

Gradle installation is not correctly configured.
Please goto Window ==> preferences ==> gradle(Enide) and configured the correct location.
What exctly I need to configure in that.

Comment: I'd guess the location of you local gradle installation.

Comment: Did you go to `Window ==> preferences ==> gradle(Enide)` on Eclipse? Isn't there an option to do as it says?

Comment: @Henry after download and install gradle in the system and giving that path worked for me